# Loading JSON from a Beautifulsoup Object

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I am currently making a scraper app, but before going full out with the app, using other frameworks like Discord.py, I had to first scrape the site first. It proved quite difficult to scrape the site. The site that I am trying to scrape from is Fiverr. Anyways, long story short, I had to get some cookies to login with Python Requests. The big issue now is that the data I need to scrape comes in the form of JSON, which I don't know much about. I managed to select the javascript in question, but once I load it it gives an error: "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Tag". I specifically need the "rows" part which is part of the JSON data.

I'm not quite certain how to fix this and have read and tried some similar questions here. I will appreciate any help.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json

# Irrelevant to the question
class JobClass:
    def __init__(self, date=None, buyer=None, request=None, duration=None, budget=None, link="https://www.fiverr.com/users/myusername/requests", id=None):
        self.date = date
        self.buyer = buyer
        self.request = request
        self.duration = duration
        self.budget = budget
        self.link = link
        self.id = id

# Irrelevant to the question
duplicateSet = set()
scrapedSet = set()
jobObjArr = []

headers = {
    # Some private cookies. To get them you just need to use a site like https://curl.trillworks.com/ it is really a life saver
    # This is used to tell the site who you are to be logged in (which is why I deleted this part out of the code)
}

# Please note that I used "myusername" in the URL. This is going to be different depending on user
# Using the requests module, we use the "get" function
# provided to access the webpage provided as an
# argument to this function:
result = requests.get(
    'https://www.fiverr.com/users/myusername/requests', headers=headers)


# Now, let us store the page content of the website accessed
# from requests to a variable:
src = result.content

# Now that we have the page source stored, we will use the
# BeautifulSoup module to parse and process the source.
# To do so, we create a BeautifulSoup object based on the
# source variable we created above:
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")

data = soup.select("[type='text/javascript']")[1]

print(data)

# TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Tag
jsonObject = json.loads(data)

# Here is the output of print(data):

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.viewData = {
            "dds": {
                "subCats": {
                    "current": {
                        "text": "All Subcategories",
                        "val": "-1"
                    },
                    "options": [{
                        "text": "Web \u0026 Mobile Design",
                        "val": 151
                    }, {
                        "text": "Web Programming",
                        "val": 140
                    }]
                }
            },
            "results": {
                "rows": [{
                        "type": "none",
                        "identifier": "5cf132b55e08360011efe633",
                        "cells": [{
                            "text": "May 31, 2019",
                            "type": "date",
                            "withText": true
                        }, {
                            "userPict": "\u003cspan class=\"missing-image-user \"\u003ec\u003c/span\u003e",
                            "type": "profile-40",
                            "cssClass": "height95"
                        }, {
                            "hintBottom": false,
                            "text": "My website was hacked and deleted. Need to have it recreated ",
                            "type": "text-wide",
                            "tags": [],
                            "attachment": false
                        }, {
                            "text": 1,
                            "type": "applications",
                            "alignCenter": true
                        }, {
                            "text": "3 days",
                            "type": "hidden-action",
                            "actionVisible": false,
                            "alignCenter": true,
                            "withText": true,
                            "buttons": [{
                                "type": "span",
                                "text": "3 days",
                                "class": "duration"
                            }, {
                                "type": "button",
                                "text": "Remove Request",
                                "class": "remove-request js-remove-request",
                                "meta": {
                                    "requestId": "5cf132b55e08360011efe633",
                                    "isProfessional": false
                                }
                            }]
                        }, {
                            "text": "---",
                            "type": "hidden-action",
                            "actionVisible": false,
                            "alignCenter": true,
                            "withText": true,
                            "buttons": [{
                                "type": "span",
                                "text": "---",
                                "class": "budget"
                            }, {
                                "type": "button",
                                "text": "Send Offer",
                                "class": "btn-standard btn-green-grad js-send-offer",
                                "meta": {
                                    "username": "conto217",
                                    "category": 3,
                                    "subCategory": 151,
                                    "requestId": "5cf132b55e08360011efe633",
                                    "requestText": "My website was hacked and deleted. Need to have it recreated ",
                                    "userPict": "\u003cspan class=\"missing-image-user \"\u003ec\u003c/span\u003e",
                                    "isProfessional": false,
                                    "buyerId": 32969684
                                }
                            }]
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "type": "none",
                        "identifier": "5cf12f641b6e99000edf1b60",
                        "cells": [{
                            "text": "May 31, 2019",
                            "type": "date",
                            "withText": true
                        }, {
                            "userPict": "\u003cimg src=\"https://fiverr-res.cloudinary.com/t_profile_small,q_auto,f_auto/attachments/profile/photo/648ceb417a85844b25e8bf070a70d9a0-254781561534997516.9743/MyFileName\"  alt=\"muazamkhokher\"  width=\"40\" height=\"40\"\u003e",
                            "type": "profile-40",
                            "cssClass": "height95"
                        }, {
                            "hintBottom": false,
                            "text": "Need mobile ui/ux designer from marvel wireframes",
                            "type": "text-wide",
                            "tags": [],
                            "attachment": false
                        }, {
                            "text": 4,
                            "type": "applications",
                            "alignCenter": true
                        }, {
                            "text": "5 days",
                            "type": "hidden-action",
                            "actionVisible": false,
                            "alignCenter": true,
                            "withText": true,
                            "buttons": [{
                                "type": "span",
                                "text": "5 days",
                                "class": "duration"
                            }, {
                                "type": "button",
                                "text": "Remove Request",
                                "class": "remove-request js-remove-request",
                                "meta": {
                                    "requestId": "5cf12f641b6e99000edf1b60",
                                    "isProfessional": false
                                }
                            }]
                        }, {
                            "text": "$50",
                            "type": "hidden-action",
                            "actionVisible": false,
                            "alignCenter": true,
                            "withText": true,
                            "buttons": [{
                                "type": "span",
                                "text": "$50",
                                "class": "budget"
                            }, {
                                "type": "button",
                                "text": "Send Offer",
                                "class": "btn-standard btn-green-grad js-send-offer",
                                "meta": {
                                    "username": "muazamkhokher",
                                    "category": 3,
                                    "subCategory": 151,
                                    "requestId": "5cf12f641b6e99000edf1b60",
                                    "requestText": "Need mobile ui/ux designer from marvel wireframes",
                                    "userPict": "\u003cimg src=\"https://fiverr-res.cloudinary.com/t_profile_small,q_auto,f_auto/attachments/profile/photo/648ceb417a85844b25e8bf070a70d9a0-254781561534997516.9743/MyFileName\"  alt=\"muazamkhokher\"  width=\"100\" height=\"100\"\u003e",
                                    "isProfessional": false,
                                    "buyerId": 25478156
                                }
                            }]
                        }]
                        ....
```

I expect the JSON to be loaded in jsonObject, but I get an error: "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Tag"

Edit: Here is some code at the end of the print statement. It randomly cuts off for some reason with no ending script tag:

```py
        }, {
            "type": "none",
            "identifier": "5cf1236a959aa5000f1ce094",
            "cells": [{
                        "text": "May 31, 2019",
                        "type": "date",
                        "withText": true
                    }, {
                        "userPict": "\u003cimg src=\"https://fiverr-res.cloudinary.com/t_profile_small,q_auto,f_auto/profile/photos/30069758/original/Universalco_2a_Cloud.png\"  alt=\"clarky2000\"  width=\"40\" height=\"40\"\u003e",
                        "type": "profile-40",
                        "cssClass": "height95"
                    }, {
                        "hintBottom": false,
                        "text": "Slider revolution slider. 3 slides for a music festival. I can supply a copy what each slide should look like (see attached) and all the individual objects. Anyone can create basic RS slides, but I want this to be dynamic as its for a music festival. We are using the free version of RS if were are required to use the paid version of SL for addons please let us know. Bottom line this must be 3 dynamic slides (using the same background) for a music festival audience. Unlimited revisions is a must.",
                        "type": "see-more",
                        "tags": [{
                            "text": "Graphic UI"
                        }, {
                            "text": "Landing Pages"
                        }],
                        "attachment": {
                            "url": "/download/file/1559260800%2Fgig_requests%2Fattachment_f2a5f51b9fb473e8fc7f498929f39e3f",
                            "name": "Outwith Rotator_1920x1080_1.jpg",
                            "size": "2.68 MB"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "text": 2,
                        "type": "applications",
                        "alignCenter": true
                    }, {
                        "text": "24 hours",
                        "type": "hidden-action",
                        "actionVisible": false,
                        "alignCenter": true,
                        "withText": true,
                        "buttons": [{
                            "type": "span",
                            "text": "24 hours",
                            "class": "duration"
                        }, {
                            "type": "button",
                            "text": "Remove Request",
                            "class": "remove-request js-remove-request",
                            "meta": {
                                "requestId": "5cf1236a959aa5000f1ce094",
                                "isProfessional": false
                            }
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "text": "$23",
                        "type": "hidden-action",
                        "actionVisible": false,
                        "alignCenter": true,
                        "withText": true,
                        "buttons": [{
                                    "type": "span",
                                    "text": "$23",
                                    "class": "budget"
                                }, {
                                    "type": "button",
                                    "text": "Send Of
```

Comment: Try ```tag.text```

Comment: `json.loads` accepts a string not a `Tag` type. Use `json.loads(data.string)`. Although you might need to filter out the "document.viewData ="

Comment: I tried json.loads(data.string) like suggested. The error message went away, but I got another error "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 5 (char 5)". Not sure what that means. Also, when I try json.loads(data.text) I get that same error. I also don't know if this is relevant, but when I printed data it didn't make an ending script tag. It just cuts off randomly. Here is some code at the end of the print statement: `                                }, {
                                    "type": "button",
                                    "text": "Send Of`